# Adjusting for age and gender in ANOVA

Tags: r, regression, anova

I am performing an ANOVA to compare the means of three groups. However, I need to adjust for the effects of age and gender in the ANOVA. I'm not quite sure how to go about it in R.

Conventionally, I would use this command in R

```r
model <- aov(y ~ x1)
```

`x1` is categorical with 3 levels.

Answer (score 0):

You would do regression with your categorical variables coded $(0,0)$ for category $1$, $(1,0)$ for category $2$, and $(0,1)$ for category $3$, plus the age and gender variables, so `m_full <- lm(y ~ c2 + c3 + age + gender)`, with `c1` omitted since it is all $0$s. You then compare to the model that lacks your categorical features: `m_reduced <- lm(y ~ age + gender)` via `anova(m_full, m_reduced)`.

This does an F-test of the two models the same way that an ANOVA F-test compares the model with the categorical features to a model that only has an intercept (which is what ANOVA does).

ANOVA is just a particular type of regression. If you want to add covariates, feel free.

You can condense the categorical variable into one `lm` input by calling it with `as.factor`, such as `m_full <- lm(y ~ as.factor(categorical_variable) + age + gender)`.

Comment: If I understand you well, you mean I should create dummy variables from the categorical variable and use those dummy variables to fit the linear regression

Comment: Yes, that’s what ANOVA is.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave!

Comment: @Dave: R will create the dummys for you if you remember to declare a **factor** variable: ` categorical <- factor(categorical)` Care to edit?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this rundown helpful: https://conjugateprior.org/2013/01/formulae-in-r-anova/

It covers some subtleties / annoyances when it comes to expressing nesting and error terms in formulae and offers some further reading.